# Json and variable scope

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

My error should be quite obvious but I can't find it;

I've a global variable initialized a the beginning of my class:

```
class InscriptionStageViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
var lesSemaines = [String]()
```

I try to populate this array with a distant json file using that function

```
func getSemainesStages(){
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.boisdelacambre.be/ios/json/semaines.json")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data, response, error) in
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    let listeSemaines = myJson["semaine"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                    //print(listeSemaines)

                    for i in 0...listeSemaines.count-1 {
                        var tabSem = listeSemaines[i]
                        let intituleSemaine:String = tabSem["intitule"] as! String
                        //let dateSemaine:String = tabSem["date"] as! String

                        DispatchQueue.main.sync
                            {

                                self.lesSemaines.append(intituleSemaine)
                            }

                    }

                } catch
                {
                    print("erreur Json")
                }
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

When I call my function in the viewDidLoad and then I print my global array, it's empty (the URL is correct, the json data is read correctly and when I read the data appended in the array in the loop, it print the (so) needed value...)

Thanks in advance

Comment: When do you read `lesSemaines`? Because I guess that your issue is due to the async part of the code.

Comment: What's the issue? Array is Empty?

Comment: In my viewDidLoad, I call the function and then try to print the array and it is empty (when I print it directly in the function it's OK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download takes time. Introduce another methode:

```
func updateUi() {
    print(lesSemaines)
    //pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

And call it *after* the download finished:

```
func getSemainesStages(){
    // ... your code 
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data, response, error) in
        // ... your code        
        for tabSem in listeSemaines{
             guard let intituleSemaine = tabSem["intitule"] as? String else {
                print("erreur Json")
                continue
            }
            self.lesSemaines.append(intituleSemaine)    
        }

        // update UI *after* for loop
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            updateUi()   
        }
        // ... your code
    }
}
```

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getSemainesStages()
        print(self.lesSemaines)
    }

Comment: Don't you think that it will finish the getSemainesStages() function before printing the array?

Comment: Yes, it will. As the download takes time. That is the nature of asynchronous calls. But the UI gets updated when all is done. That is why I moved the `print` in an extra method.

Comment: And how can make that call synchronous ? Because I would like to use that array for a pickerView

Comment: You do not want to make it synchronous as this would block your UI (freeze the app) while downloading. Update the pickerView in `updateUi()`. If it takes to long for good UX, show an `UIActivityIndicator` (loading spinner).

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code to Swift 3. Please replace it with below code.

```
func getSemainesStages(){
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.boisdelacambre.be/ios/json/semaines.json")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data, response, error) in
        if let content = data {
            do {
                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
                let listeSemaines = myJson["semaine"] as! [[String: Any]]

                for i in 0...listeSemaines.count-1 {
                    var tabSem = listeSemaines[i]
                    let intituleSemaine:String = tabSem["intitule"] as! String
                    self.lesSemaines.append(intituleSemaine)
                }
                print(self.lesSemaines)
            } catch {
                print("erreur Json")
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: The problem is still there; When the function print (self.lesSemaines) it print all the data perfectly. But in my ViewDidLoad when I try to print the array, it's empty. (I call the function then try to print the array)

Comment: Yes because when you call on view did load its actually empty and the code  runs on background thread. If you want to print in viewDidLoad then implement completion block or call it sync.